# How to turn off ruby thin server HTTP keep-alive?

Tags: ruby, thin, keep-alive

Currently I am spawning HTTP server within my program programmatically.

```
srv =   Thin::Server.start('0.0.0.0', 3000, app)
```

And I can't figure out where should I see to change keep-alive time setting. Because thin server do not die immediately, it bothers me when debugging and developing app. I will turn on the keep-alive for production, but still I want to control the duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #       Thin::Server.stop! doesn't work immediately if there's live keep-alive connection.
    #       SIGINT doesn't work.
    #       Only SIGKILL works.
    #       But `abort` is a lot quicker way.
    #       Overridden to abort.

    trap("INT") { puts " Force quit by raising intentional crash!" ;abort() }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it not to wait for pending requests to be served, then just call `stop!`:

```
if RAKE_ENV=='production'
  srv.stop
else
  srv.stop!
end
```

[Thin source](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/5a1e14a082f75ee56167d95e982d35e0fc8b62bf/lib/thin/server.rb#L184)

Comment: Even `srv.stop!` doesn't make the app to quid immediately.

Comment: Then can I suggest you a SIGKILL if you are running some Unix derivative or Linux? `\`kill -9 #{Process.pid}\``